# Error in archiving : clang : error : no such file or directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, cocoapods

I am using **podfile** for one of iOS project developed with **xcode 7.2**. It builds without error with simulator and device, also related libraries works properly.

But when I try to Archive app to create build it fails with **error log** as

> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Crittercism'
>   clang: error: no such file or directory: 'DownPicker'

I have tried with reinstalling these two pod-libs from terminal, Cleaning derived data. Also making its search path as recursive and referred many other stack overflow related questions and answered but none of them worked in my case.

This has ruined my life since last day. Please help. Any help is appreciated.

**Please check the attached image for more details.**

[image: Complete error log image]

Comment: There are several instances of `-framework -framework` on that command line.  Check your *build settings*.  If the worse comes to the worse, save recent changes and rollback to a previous `git` commit.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thank you very much.. You have saved my life...

Comment: For those who are facing the same problem, i would like to tell you that when we add or remove any pod framework we need to also remove its reference from other linker flag of build settings.. cheers..